# Search according to the first letter entered in an Input

Tags: html, css, typescript, sass

I have an  search bar type Input where the user can select a new conversation.
With my code, when the user clicks on the search bar the entire list is displayed. I would like to be able to filter this list according to the letter entered by the user.
If he types an 'A', I would like to show that the first names that start with an 'A'.

Here is my code of my component 'list-container':

```
<div class="new-chat-window">
  <div class="search-bar">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    <input class="new-chat-window-input"
           id="new-chat-window-input"
           placeholder="Rechercher"
           (click)="threadService.openList()"/>
  </div>

  <div class="list-container">
    <list-user
      *ngFor="let thread of threadService.orderedThreads | async"
      [thread]="thread">
    </list-user>
  </div>
</div>

.display-new-chat-window {

  .new-chat-window {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    input:focus { outline-color: $blue; }
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;

    .fa {
      position: absolute;
      padding-top: 20px;
      padding-left: 7px;
      color: $grey;
    }

    .new-chat-window-input {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      line-height: 30px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      padding-left: 25px;
      width: 190px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
  }
}

.display-list {

  .list-container {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Here is my code of my component 'list-user' :

```
<div class="user-list">
  <div class="logo-user">
    {{thread.participants[0].name.split(" ")[0].substr(0, 1) + thread.participants[0].name.split(" ")[1].substr(0, 1)}}
  </div>

  <div class="name-user">
    {{thread.participants[0].name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to achieve this TypeScript ?

Comment: HTML and CSS are only the presentation of the data. If you want to act on user input in the browser you'll have to do that with JavaScript. But your HTML-code looks like you are using some JavaScript framwork (Angular perhaps?) anyway.

Comment: @BjörnTantau
Ok, yes I use the Angular 4 framework.